# How can we create Mega Menu in SharePoint Classic Publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, megamenu

I tried to look into many blogs but did not find and correct direction to create Mega Menu in SharePoint Classic Publishing site

Comment: What are you trying to do? "Mega Menu" is kind of vague... What have you tried so far? What does not work?

Comment: I want to display Top Navigation as a Mega Menu in my SharePoint 2016 classic publishing site with Managed Metadata navigation just like available in SharePoint Online

Comment: okey. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to follow https://support.bindtuning.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001046626-Set-a-Mega-Menu blog but did not find jquery elements in my master page mentioned in the blog

Comment: That's probably because the article builds upon a product of that company which has to be installed first.. Did you install it?

Comment: No I did not install any application because I want to implement mega menu without any third party tool

Answer (score 0):

I'm not associated with this company, but I've used them in the past, for $150 you can't code a solution that cheap.

https://www.sharepointmegamenus.com